# Adding border to series in a bar chart

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I am using a macro to insert a chart into a spreadsheet:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

    Dim overskrifter As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim høgde As Long, breidde As Long

    Call fjernkurver

    i = 1
    høgde = 240: breidde = 350
    Set overskrifter = Oppsummering.Range("C5:L5")

    With Kurver.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered)
        .Name = "Graf_" & i
        With .Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .XValues = overskrifter
            .Values = overskrifter.Offset(i, 0)
            .Name = Oppsummering.Range("B5").Offset(i, 0)
            ' "Olive"
            .Points(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(128, 128, 0)
            ' "Dark khaki"
            .Points(8).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(189, 183, 107)
            ' Green (Atlantis)
            .Points(9).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
            With .Format.Line
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .Weight = 0.5
                '.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 205)
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                .Transparency = 0
            End With
        End With
        .Height = høgde
        .Width = breidde
        .Top = 5 + ((i - 1) \ 3) * (5 + høgde)
        .Left = 5 + ((i - 1) Mod 3) * (5 + breidde)
        .Chart.HasTitle = True
        .Chart.ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 150
        .Chart.ChartGroups(1).Overlap = 0
    End With
End Sub

Sub fjernkurver()
    Dim co As ChartObject

    For Each co In Kurver.ChartObjects
        co.Delete
    Next co
End Sub
```

For the most part it works fine, but I am having some issues with this part of the code:

```
        With .Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .Weight = 0.5
            '.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 205)
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .Transparency = 0
        End With
```

It is supposed to add a border around all the bars in the graph, red with RGB(255,0,0), blue with RGB(0,0,255).

However, as far as I can tell, no border is added to any of the bars. Can someone please point out where I am going wrong here?

The chart ends up looking like this:
[image]

Comment: my solution work? was a bit hard following code

Comment: @learnAsWeGo No

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears that the `.Format.Line` property of a series applies to something else than the border of a bar chart - a guess would be that it is the line connecting the datapoints of e.g. a line or scatter chart.

To actually outline the bars, I replaced the offending code;

```
With .Format.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .Weight = 0.5
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Transparency = 0
End With
```

with

```
.Border.LineStyle = xlContinuous
.Border.Color = 9851952
.Format.Line.Weight = 0.5
```

Please don't ask me why `.Format.Line.Weight` still applies to the border, at least I got it working. Big props to the people who'd written [the thread where I found the answer on Ozgrid forums](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/99847-weight-of-border-on-a-column-chart-in-vba).